# Stats in Google Search Console dropped off after chaning domain and moving to HTTPS, but analytics traffic is steady

Tags: google-search-console, traffic

I have two sites where the data in GWT has done this

**Site 1 past 90 days**
[image: site 1]

**Site 2 past 28 days**
[image: site 2]

Notice the huge drop-offs in data - but when I look at any other analytics tools such as GA or the stats in Wordpress, everything is fine.

The first site has a massive dip in impressions and clicks, but position and CTR have recovered a little, but are still off.

The second site has just disappeared completely.

1. Is Google just having a bad day/week/month?
2. Should I expect this to just recover on its own?
3. Should I contact Google?

Comment: If GA and wp stats does not show any drop, then you should look into crawl report. And any changes you've done in past? like switch from http to https? or domain/URL changed?

Comment: Both sites have recently changed to https, as well as changing hosts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need add the HTTPS version of your site to Google Search Console and verify that.   When you move from HTTP to HTTPS, the data no longer appears in the HTTP property that you have been using.   It will now only go into the HTTPS property in Google Search Console.

If you want to see the stats for both together, you can create a [property set](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6338828?hl=en) that contains both versions.